# 80s or 90s fantasy book where the protagonist must travel back in time to recruit people to help him fight a war

Tags: story-identification, books

I started reading a book in 2001. All I remember is the protagonist must travel back in time to recruit people to help him fight a war.  I believe Amelia Earhart is one of the characters.

Comment: The plot sounds vaguely like the short-lived comic book *Aztec Ace*. Amelia Earhart is part of it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_Ace

Comment: A longshot possibility found by googling: *Amelia Earhart and the Flying Chariot*. https://www.amazon.com/Amelia-Earhart-Flying-Chariot-Twisters/dp/1250148995

Comment: This was definitely a long chapter book. Likely 500pgs.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer.

It's from **the Atlantis Series by Bob Mayer.**

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. We'd be grateful if you edited this answer to provide some info on the plot of this book (whichever one in the series you think the OP is likely to have read), to help other users determine how likely this is to be the correct answer. Specifying the year in which the book was published would be helpful too.

Comment: The blurb for [the fifth book](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/18874043) mentions Amelia Earhart.

Comment: Yes, I found a copy of the fifth book in the series, [Assault on Atlantis](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18874043-assault-on-atlantis), and it does match the rather brief description given in the question.

Comment: This may be it!!  Thanks!!